# How to filter old log cat runs

Tags: android, android-studio

Every-time I run the application, I see old output from the last run above the new output. This is confusing and therefore annoying. How do I filter out the old output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the restart logging button highlighted below. 
Edit: The green circular arrow icon.
[image: Logcat]